# change value from texbox with scrollbar in xaml .NET FrameWork

Tags: .net, xaml, visual-studio-code, frameworks, visual-studio-2019

I've got a textBox with a overlaid scrollbar and I want to change the values from the textbox with the scrollbar. Imagine you are selecting a color and want to go throw 0 to 255 with the arrows of the scrollbar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Slider for that, because it does exactly what you want. Controlling values with a "thumb" that you can move to scale.

**Edit**:
You can also do it with a Scrollbar by subscribing to its events that are fired when the scroll postition changes and then change the value in the text box accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that would be deffinetly usefull, but there is a way to change it with the arrows of the scrollbar, maybe a difficult way but thats what I need, thanks for the reply!